# How to set values for a specific row

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, database

I currently have a database filled with source and destination IP addresses and other details about those paths. I'm now tasked to create multiple columns depending on the number of distinct paths that my database has. A sample of which is shown in the screenshot below :

[image: Columns must be added depending on the number of distinct rows]

Each column will then correspond to a distinct Path. P1 would correspond to the first distinct path, P2 would correspond to the second distinct path, and so on. The values of the "P" columns are only 1 and 0, depending on the value of "Path". The value will be equal to 1 if the value of the record/row on the "Path" column is equal to the value that a certain column corresponds to. Sample of which is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Values on each column depend on the value of "Path"]

Question: is there any way to automate the addition of the columns and assignment of those values (either in Java or MySQL, if this is possible)? My database currently has more than 30,000 records, with more than 450 distinct "Path" values.

Comment: Why don't you split up the value in the Path column into Path_From and Path_To parts (using `->` as delimeter). You can then just `COUNT(DISTINCT Path_From)` to calculate the number of paths.

Comment: That's because if I do that, it's just counting the number of distinct "Path_From" addresses, not considering that a "Path_From" can go to two or more "Path_To" addresses. There would be a conflict if address a.a.a.a would be counted alone if we do not consider that there's a path a.a.a.a->b.b.b.b and a.a.a.a->c.c.c.c